# Using folder name of output file inside SAGA GIS Algorithm with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, saga

I want to execute an algorithm using SAGA GIS. I am using the following Python code.

```
outputwinddata_asc = "W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/Thailand_Rectangle2_DTU50m.asc"
outputwinddata_asc1 = "W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/Thailand_Rectangle2_DTU50m_SAGA.asc"
processing.runalg("saga:reclassifygridvalues",outputwinddata_asc,0,-999.0,0,0,0,1,2,0,"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",0,True,0,False,0,outputwinddata_asc1)
```

Its showing (as given below) that the output file is generated successfully.

```
{'RESULT': 'W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/SAGA.asc'}
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to see any file with file name SAGA.asc in the folder W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles.

Then, I tried by changing the folder of output file as given below.

```
outputwinddata_asc1 = "C:/Users/Sreeraj/Desktop/SAGA.asc"
```

Then the output file SAGA.asc is generated successfully in the folder C:/Users/Sreeraj/Desktop ; and I can see the output.

```
{'RESULT': 'W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/SAGA.asc'}
```

So, I found out that the difference is the spacing of folder names. C:/Users/Sreeraj/Desktop does not have any spaces in between folder names. But, for `W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles`, there are spaces for `04 Tools` and `07 MapMaker` ( I mean 07 'space' MapMaker).

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to remove these spaces of folder names and I must keep the folder name `W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles` as it is.

How can I solve this issue (without changing the name of output folder `W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles`) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123198/how-do-i-copy-a-file-in-python

Comment: It's not always a problem with the spaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14852407/930271. But try with `'"W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/SAGA.asc"'` Test in a console that the path really exists and you have permissions on it.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga That doesn't helped me. Only this algorithm is not giving output files to the folder W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/ . Maybe, SAGA GIS algorithms will not allow to use the folder names with spaces. The path really exists and the output is not generated only in the folders with spaces between characters. If the output folder name is in desktop, then output file is generated there (as mentioned in the question) without any issues because the full characters of the folder name of desktop used in question doesnot have any spaces.

Comment: @fatih_dur This question is not regarding copying files. Please try to solve this issue after reading the entire question.

Comment: You could try windows short file name, like here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286179-getshortpathname/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using the Python recipe of win32api.GetShortPathName() as given below.

```
import win32api
outputwinddata_asc = win32api.GetShortPathName("W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/Thailand_Rectangle2_DTU50m.asc")
outputwinddata_asc1 = win32api.GetShortPathName("W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/Thailand_Rectangle2_DTU50m_SAGA.asc")
processing.runalg("saga:reclassifygridvalues",outputwinddata_asc,0,-999.0,0,0,0,1,2,0,"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",0,True,0,False,0,outputwinddata_asc1)
```

The above code solved the issue perfectly.

The only condition is that the win32api.GetShortPathName() will only works if the file already exists in the specified path.

If the output file doesnot exists in the output path, then it is possible to solve this issue prefectly as given below.

```
import win32api
outputwinddata_asc = win32api.GetShortPathName("W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/") + "Thailand_Rectangle2_DTU50m.asc"
outputwinddata_asc1 = win32api.GetShortPathName("W:/04 Tools/07 MapMaker/workingfiles/") + "Thailand_Rectangle2_DTU50m_SAGA.asc"
processing.runalg("saga:reclassifygridvalues",outputwinddata_asc,0,-999.0,0,0,0,1,2,0,"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",0,True,0,False,0,outputwinddata_asc1)
```